# K2 Joomla: How to get category id from a single article page?

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I am trying to grab the category id from a single item (article) K2 page. I tried doing:

```
JRequest::getVar( 'catid' )
```

But that returns blank. I am running this code from index.php and not item.php, so I don't have access to the `$item` object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try use the following:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT catid FROM #__k2_items WHERE id = 1";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();

echo $result;
```

You will need to change `id = 1` to whatever the id of your article is.

Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

for get current itemid modified query is

```
$item_id = JRequest::getVar('Itemid');
$db = & JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT catid FROM #__k2_items WHERE id =".$item_id;
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();

echo $result;
```